# Cannot convert type 'TOutput' to 'System.DateTime' when using converter

Tags: c#, datetime

I am getting error at this line

" array[i, j] = ((DateTime)array[i, j]).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");"

error message : Cannot convert type 'TOutput' to 'System.DateTime'

Please help me.

```
        var ObjJagArr = Dt.AsEnumerable()
                        .Select(row => row.ItemArray).ToArray();

        object[,] MultiArr = ConvertAll(ObjJagArr, x => x);


    public static TOutput[,] ConvertAll<TInput, TOutput>(
        this TInput[][] Jarr, Func<TInput, TOutput> converter)
    {

        int rows = Jarr.Length;
        int cols = Jarr.Max(subArray => subArray.Length);
        TOutput[,] array = new TOutput[rows, cols];
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            {
                array[i, j] = converter(Jarr[i][j]);
                if (array[i, j].GetType().Name.Equals("DateTime"))
                {
                    //array[i, j] = ((DateTime)array[i, j]).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
                    string strDt = Convert.ToDateTime(array[i, j]).ToShortDateString();
                    array[i, j] = (TOutput)(object)strDt; 
                }

            }
        }


        return array;
    }
```

solved the issue.
I forget the matter of boxing

Comment: As far as I know C# only states this if it is sure `TOutput` and `DateTime` cannot be the same type.

Comment: You are trying to assign a `string` RHS `((DateTime)array[i, j]).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")` to a `TOutput` LHS `array[i, j]`. There is all sorts of wrong in this code. Quite frankly I would say you should start from scratch and just tell us what you want done.

Comment: If one of the column's data type is datetime, i just need to print in date value only. I want to eliminate time from DateTime.

Comment: Why do you have `.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");` You are casting a string to `DateTime` .

Comment: Hi, Aron u r correct. I am trying to fix with your suggestion

Comment: any class info about TOutput?

Comment: That particular cellvalue shows me datetime, so i thought i can cast to string with format.

Comment: still i couldn't find any solution

Comment: What is the signature of your converter method?

Comment: Func<TInput, TOutput>. i think i hv used <object, object>